# Multithreading and JList

Tags: multithreading, jlist

I keep getting index out of bounds errors and Eclipse is not telling me why or what line of my code is causing this! This is a multithreading assignment and my code works somewhat. We are to have one thread look up all files from the directory that the user provides and the other thread is used for when the user clicks a file from the JList and it writes the text from the text file selected into a textArea on the right. But the main issue is that the JList sometimes shows and sometimes doesn't after clicking the search button and also that index out of bounds exception.

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;



public class Atlas
{
    JList<String> list;

    DefaultListModel<String> model;



    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel lblDirectory;
    private JTextField inputDirectory;
    private JLabel lblExtension;
    private JTextField inputExtension;
    private JButton btnSearch;

    private Scanner reader;
    private JPanel southPanel;
    private JScrollPane pane;

    private JTextArea text;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Atlas p = new Atlas();
        p.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(984, 503);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        list = new JList<String>();


        pane = new JScrollPane(list);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270,300));

        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.WEST);




        lblDirectory = new JLabel("Start Directory:");
        inputDirectory = new JTextField();
        lblExtension = new JLabel("File Extension:");
        inputExtension = new JTextField();
        btnSearch = new JButton("Search");





        lblDirectory.setSize(64, 20);
        inputDirectory.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        lblExtension.setSize(64, 20);
        inputExtension.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,20));

        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Thread myThread = new Finder();
                myThread.start();

               // listFiles(inputDirectory.getText());
            }
        });



        //Text Area
        text = new JTextArea(200,32);
        JScrollPane textPane = new JScrollPane();
        textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270,300));
        textPane.add(text);
        frame.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);



        Thread myThread2 = new Counter2();
        myThread2.start();



        southPanel = new JPanel();

        //Making bottom visible
        southPanel.add(lblDirectory);
        southPanel.add(inputDirectory);
        southPanel.add(lblExtension);
        southPanel.add(inputExtension);
        southPanel.add(btnSearch);
        frame.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // show the window
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Finder extends Thread
    {
        public int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //while(true)
            {

                listFiles(inputDirectory.getText());









                System.out.println("a: " + count);

            }
        }
    }





     public void listFiles(String path)
        {
            File root = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = root.listFiles();

            if(listOfFiles == null) return;

            for(File f: listOfFiles)
            {
                if(f.isDirectory())
                {
                    listFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    //JTextField button = new JTextField(f.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                    //listFiles.add(button);
                    model.addElement(f.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                    list.setModel(model);
                    System.out.println("Dir: " + f.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                    //crap.addElement(f.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Dir: " + f.getAbsoluteFile());
                    model.addElement(f.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                }
            }



        }


    class Counter2 extends Thread
    {

        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //while(true)
            {
                list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
                {
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            File file = new File(list.getSelectedValue());
                            System.out.println(list.getSelectedValue());
                            System.out.println("hi");
                            reader = new Scanner(file);
                            while(reader.hasNextLine())
                            {
                                text.append(reader.nextLine());
                                text.append("\n");
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error Connecting To File");
                        }


                    }
                });

                System.out.println("b: " + count);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exact exception is

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3736
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1368)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1311)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.getCellBounds(BasicListUI.java:952)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:304)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:777)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5223)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5171)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4982)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:824)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Please show the exact exception and what line it occurs in your sourcecode.

Comment: I think you have a data race accessing  DefaultListModel<String> model. Not sure if this is related to your exception i think the stacktrace could help.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: The `model.addElement` and `list.setModel` calls must be done in the EDT and the `Finder` thread is running outside of the EDT. Wrap the method calls in a `Runnable` and call [EventQueue.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) with the created `Runnable`.